# Why my Spock unit tests fail in Gradle build after upgrading to JDK 8?

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, gradle, java-8, spock

I'm trying to compile my application source using JDK 8, Groovy 2.4.4, Spock 1.0-groovy-2.4, Gradle 1.11 (my firm hass custom plugins built on top of this)

```
gradle -version
Groovy:       1.8.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013
Ivy:          2.2.0
JVM:          1.7.0_51 (Oracle Corporation 24.51-b03)
OS:           Windows 7 6.1 amd64
```

In my build environment, I need to retain my `JAVA_HOME` to Java 7 for other projects.

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51
JAVA8_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60
```

Due to this, in my build.gradle, I explicitly tell Gradle to use JDK 8

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.fork = true;
    options.forkOptions.executable = "${System.env.JAVA8_HOME}/bin/javac"
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    executable = "${System.env.JAVA8_HOME}/bin/java"
}

compileJava{
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
}
```

The source files compile successfully, however when it reached unit tests (written in Spock), it fails with the below error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/model/SDA : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

I confirmed that SDA.class is compiled using JDK 8.

```
javap -verbose SDA.class | findstr "major"
  major version: 52
```

Any reason why only during unit tests I get the above error? Does that mean unit test is being run on JDK 7?

Comment: Can you try `executable = "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/bin/java"` ?

Comment: Is expression `${System.env.JAVA8_HOME}` evaluated to a valid value?

Comment: @Opal, Yes, I verified that JAVA8_HOME is a valid value.

Comment: Aby chance to reproduce it somehow?

Comment: @Opal, Unfortunately we use a custom-built of gradle with custom plugins. I'll try to replicate this a small mock up project with plain vanilla Gradle and JDK 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you're really into hacks there is something you can do. It does involve overriding some of the Gradle internals - so it may not work on any version of Gradle other than 1.11. There may also be unexpected side-effects.

```
import org.gradle.internal.Factory
import org.gradle.process.internal.WorkerProcessBuilder
import org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.CompilerDaemonStarter

tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) {
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.executable = "${System.env.JAVA8_HOME}/bin/javac"

    doFirst {
        def compilerFactory = compiler.compiler.compilerFactory
        def clientsManager = compilerFactory.compilerDaemonManager.clientsManager
        def oldDaemonStarter = clientsManager.compilerDaemonStarter
        if (!(oldDaemonStarter.workerFactory instanceof CustomWorkerProcessFactory)) {
            println "HACK, installing custom daemon worker"
            clientsManager.compilerDaemonStarter = new CompilerDaemonStarter(
                    new CustomWorkerProcessFactory(oldDaemonStarter.workerFactory),
                    oldDaemonStarter.startParameter)
        }
    }
}

class CustomWorkerProcessFactory implements Factory<WorkerProcessBuilder> {
    Factory<WorkerProcessBuilder> delegate

    CustomWorkerProcessFactory(Factory<WorkerProcessBuilder> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate
    }

    public WorkerProcessBuilder create() {
        def newWorker = delegate.create()
        newWorker.javaCommand.executable("${System.env.JAVA8_HOME}/bin/java")
        newWorker
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution finally worked for me. Spock unit tests using Spy feature was failing during cglib issue (see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spockframework/59WIHGgcSNE). After switching to cglib:cglib:3.1 as mentioned in the link, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.java.home=/path/to/java8
```

Or when you launch gradle, you can specify it as a jvm parameter:

```
gradle -Dorg.gradle.java.home=/path/to/java8 task1 task2
```

Comment: If that doesn't work for you - then this is what I got from a Gradle support engineer (my company has a support contract...):

Gradle 1.11 is not going to work with JDK8.

So, there's no good solution here. I traced through the way the Groovy compiler daemon is started, and the only way to modify the command line is to change internal code.

Comment: Thanks Eric. This is apparently a bug in Gradle. https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-3343

Comment: Yeah they created that bug based on my support forum interaction with them today. I found your post here first and after banging my head on it for a few hours today I decided to just take your post and send it to them to see what they had to say about it.